# What does the Exclamation Mark in QT Stylesheets mean?

Tags: qtstylesheets

Within the code here, what does the ! in front of editable mean?

```
QTextEdit:!editable,
QTextEdit:!editable:focus {
   color: #f5f5f5;
   background-color: #3c3c3c;
   border: 6px  solid #333333;
   border-radius: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means the negation of the state, not editable in your case.
See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html